# wso2-das cannot implement real-time analysis

Tags: real-time, wso2-das

I wrote a py code to capture some information and send to DAS through kafka. Now I can see when I run the code, data can successfully printed on cmd of DAS. I config the receiver on DAS is HTTP, and these data can be drawn successfully when using batch analysis when I config the parameter as persisted. But when I switch to real-time analysis and change the parameter not to be persisted, the dashboard reminds me that there is no data in the stream.
What is the reason for this case?

Comment: where do you change the parameter not be persisted? Could you please mention the DAS production as well ?

Comment: I set the parameters of the stream to be not persisted at first, after finding this method cannot shows data, I set persisted in "Stream".

Answer (score 0):

Changing stream persist to not persist just make sure data is not persisted to underlying event table. Actually you need to change the gadget provider by specifying batch or real time in the dashboard portal. Please gadget creation documentation [1]. There you can create a real time gadget by specifying the provider and selecting stream. Then you can place that gadget in the dashboard designer.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Analytics+Dashboard#AnalyticsDashboard-Step2:CreaterequiredgadgetsGadget